# Node.js Console "UI" & I/O Control

Tags: node.js, logging, io, command-line-interface, next.js

I see a lot of times with CLI programs the terminal window tends to be very clean and reading/writing seems to be very controlled.

Examples that come to mind include:

- **git bash**: where if your input gets interrupted by some asynchronous output, it will simply reprint it on a new line's `$`
- **minecraft server**: where the terminal input is on a completely different line from the server logs

My questions are:

1. What is this called/what is the correct terminology to describe this?
2. Is this doable in Node.js, in order to send commands to the server while tasks are being run and logged?
3. If so, is it complicated to reroute logging that I don't have control over? For example, next.js just seems to dump stuff into the terminal. (On that note, how do they handle 'clearing' the terminal window?)

To clarify, I'm not wondering about how to implement command parsing, colouring/formatting, or logging conventions (I've easily found topics/node packages that deal with all those), but rather how to control it all and keep a clean interface to improve UX.

Comment: If anyone cares to leave a comment on why my question should be downvoted, I'm always open to feedback on how to keep the site healthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you are looking for is TUI (Text User Interface), haven't used this in a very long time but curses/ncurses (don't remember the difference) are the keywords you are looking for, quick npm search gives [blessed](https://github.com/chjj/blessed#documentation) as a node.js binding of ncurses, this should get you on the right path